# Sightly syntax to retrieve crx/de properties in jsp/html page

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6

I would like to retrieve some properties e.g. jcr:created using Sightly or any related syntax for the panel component in AEM adaptive forms. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iEiC.png)

The previous Sighlty syntaxes that I have attempted to retrieve the crx/de properties include:

```
${properties.jcr:created}
${pageProperties\[jcr:created\].getTime.toString}
${guidePanel.jcr:created}
${resource.jcr:created}]
```

I have tried the following syntaxes but unable to retrieve the value from the property and in worst cases, the component may not be rendered on screen.

I have looked up on Adobe forum sites and past stackoverflow questions that other people may have asked. I have tried the solutions and given answers but was unable to achieve the result. I would greatly appreciate for any help or sharing of applicable knowledge if you have encountered similar issues or previously attempted to solve similar problems. Thank you!

Comment: `${properties['jcr:created'].time.toString}` works in sightly.

Comment: I have tried the following slightly code but am still unable to get the value from the crx/de properties as stated.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the HTL (aka Sightly) syntax? In a jsp (since there is a "jsp" in your headline...) ?

Comment: @OliverGebert I am trying to use it in a html page

Answer (score 0):

You can always create Use class in Java or Javascript to access these properties, it's cleaner and testable. Better than that, you can use Sling Models which are more readable and easier to implement, here is a good presentation about it https://www.slideshare.net/accunitysoft/understanding-sling-models-in-aem

Answer (score 0):

Properties of resources are readable without any extra definitions needed.
So you might want to check what resource is handled in your component by adding this:

```
${resource.path}
```

Then you can check the returned path in CRXDE if there really is a jcr:created property available at this path - which should be the case if you are accessing a resource that has a proper sling resource type. Then this call should give a valid return value:

```
${resource.path} ___ created: 
${properties.jcr:created.getTime.toString}
```

If the path is not displayed as well, then it would help if you could post

- the repo path of the content resource you are processing
- the sling:resourceType
- the path to the component's ht(m)l file that you are using